# How to get Ocrad.js example to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ocr

I am making an OCR (optical character recognition) web application, and I found the JavaScript library [Ocrad.js](http://antimatter15.github.io/ocrad.js/demo.html), which is exactly what I was looking for, but I can't get it to work. Can somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="ocrad.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var image = document.getElementById('image');
                var string = OCRAD(image);
                alert(string);
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <img src="img.jpg" id="image">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please be much more specific. What does "can't get it to work" mean?

Comment: I would use the path to the image to define 'image'

Answer (score 4):

You can't just pass an `<img>` element to the `OCRAD()` function.

From the [Ocrad.js documentation](http://antimatter15.github.io/ocrad.js/demo.html):

> This file exposes a single global function, OCRAD which takes
>   an image as an argument and returns the recognized text as a string.
>   [...] The `image` argument can be a canvas element, a Context2D
>   instance, or an instance of ImageData.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $('#image');

    var context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage($img[0], 0, 0);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, $img.width(), $img.height());

    var string = OCRAD(imageData);
    alert(string);
});
```

But you may have to put `width` and `height` attributes on your `<img>` element in order for this to work.

---

If you attempt to pass an `<img>` element to the `OCRAD()` function, you will get the following error:

> uncaught exception: 5264272 - Exception catching is disabled, this
>   exception cannot be caught. Compile with -s
>   DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 or DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=2 to catch.

If you attempt to pass a jQuery object to the `OCRAD()` function, you will get the following error:

> Error: invalid arguments

---

Note: Because of the Same Origin Policy, the call to `context.getImageData()` will throw a `SecurityError` if the URL for the image does not have the same domain as the page it is on.

Comment: Hi @John S, this was not helped me can u plz check my code with `function imageLoaded(ev) {
    element = document.getElementById("cancan");
    c = element.getContext("2d");
    im = ev.target;
    width = element.width;
    height = element.height;
    c.drawImage(im, 0, 0);
 var data1=OCRAD(c);
 console.log(data1);
}

im = new Image();
im.src = "message.png";
im.onload = imageLoaded;`   and I'm getting **Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on CanvasRenderingContext2D: the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.**

Comment: @NithinCVpoyyil - The URL for the image must have the same domain as the page it is on, or else the call to `context.getImageData()` will throw a `SecurityError`.

Comment: I am facing this issue. How to fix it. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.