# ocrad.js- OCR Javascript Library throwing Uncaught SecurityError on passing HTML5 canvas to OCRAD() API

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, ocr, filereader

I'm a newbie in HTML5+JS, I want to develop an hybrid app using **[`ocrad.js`](https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js)**.

The **[code given below](https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js/blob/master/examples/file.html)**,  downloaded from github page is perfectly working for me(Chrome 32.0.1).

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="../ocrad.js"></script>
        <script>
            function OCRImage(image){
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
                canvas.width  = image.naturalWidth;
                canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0)
                return OCRAD(canvas)
            }

            function OCRPath(url, callback){
                var image = new Image()
                image.src = url;
                image.onload = function(){ callback(OCRImage(image)) }
            }

            function OCRFile(file, callback){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(){ OCRPath(reader.result, callback); }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            }
        </script>
        <input type="file" onchange="OCRFile(this.files[0], function(text){alert(text)})">
    </body> 
</html>
```

When I called `OCRAD() API` in my code its giving **Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.**

**My CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../ocrad.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="cancan" width="800", height="500">Test image</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

function imageLoaded(ev) {
    element = document.getElementById("cancan");
    c = element.getContext("2d");
    im = ev.target;
    width = element.width;
    height = element.height;
    c.drawImage(im, 0, 0);
    var data1=OCRAD(c);
    console.log(data1);
}

im = new Image();
im.src = "message.png";
im.onload = imageLoaded;
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have seen similar **[Stackoverflow Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963172/how-to-get-ocrad-js-example-to-work/20964363#20964363)** but it didn't help me to solve the issue. Please answer if any one had any comment on this issue who have worked with Ocrad.js.

**OR**

Is there anyother way to pass my image file (here **message.png** in second code example) as an argument to `OCRFile()` function in first code example ?  (Simply I want to pass an image stored in an local file URL to `OCRAD()` Call to return text. )

Thanks in advance.... :)

Comment: Does any have any useful information please share It may help me to solve the issue...

Comment: You need to load the image from the same origin as the page (file:// not included) or from a server which allow cross-origin use (and if so request crossOrigin usage).

Comment: Thanks Epistemex, Issue is pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963172/how-to-get-ocrad-js-example-to-work/20964363?noredirect=1#comment36040411_20964363  by John S. Is it possible to allow crossorigin usage in my case?

Comment: If you move the image in question to the same origin (domain etc.) as your page it should work. Otherwise it will depend on the external server if it allows it or not. You can request CORS usage but the server may reject it. You can request by setting `im.crossOrigin = '';` *before* setting the src property.

Comment: Actually I dont want it to in server, rather I want it as local HTML5 application with webcam. Usecase is simple take picture using Camera API of HTML5  and pass it to that OCRAD API.

Comment: For webcam you need to use getUserMedia which is not related to image loading per-se (it shouldn't cause any CORS issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a cross-origin issue which is a security mechanism in browsers.

You will either need to:

- Move image to same origin as the page (origin = domain, port and protocol)
- Request CORS usage from the other origin if you can't move the image
- Use a proxy page to load the image (see **[one in action here](http://www.corsproxy.com/)** - note: I do not know this site so use only for testing with non-critical data).

A request can be made like this (assuming `im` contains the image you want to OCR treat):

```
function imageLoaded(ev) {
    element = document.getElementById("cancan");
    c = element.getContext("2d");
    width = element.width;
    height = element.height;
    c.drawImage(this, 0, 0);  // 'this' = current image loaded
    var data1 = OCRAD(c);
    console.log(data1);
}

var im = new Image();
im.onload = imageLoaded;      // set onload before src
im.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; // request CORS usage before setting src
im.src = "message.png";
```

If a request will work is entirely up to the server which may deny the request (which is default behavior in most cases).

In that case only moving the image or setting up a proxy page to load the external image will allow usage of it. Note that file:// or local files are considered different origins.

A proxy page is in essence a page you pass the image url to as an argument. The page will then, on server side, load the image and pass the data back to your first (requesting) page. This way you can "stream" the image through your own server removing CORS restrictions but at the expense of increased traffic on your own server. Some server may also block this approach by denying external access (ie. by referrer or IP etc.)

See **[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)** for more details.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply. Can you please elaborate 3rd case **Use a proxy page to load the image**  ?